# JQuery select and deselect toggle issue?

Tags: jquery, function, click, toggle

Im having trouble with a jquery function where i have 5 option boxes (which when clicked checks a checkbox) and a checkbox for "none of these".

I am trying to create a function where you can select multiple options, and by checking the "none of these" checkbox, it resets them and, and vice versa where if you again select an option (or multiple), the "none of these" checkbox becomes unchecked.

Think of it as a market research question!

Copy of it below

http://jsfiddle.net/pGgkT/

Problem i am having is when i select, for example option 5,4,3 and then click "none of these", then go bac to select 5,4,3, they take 2 clicks to select instead of just 1 which is only necessary for the others i didnt select originally (1,2).

Comment: I don't see the double click behavior in Chrome 13.

Comment: sorry, when selecting the choices don't click on the checkbox..click on the image above it. those choice checkboxes will eventually be hidden. thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toggle internally adds a click handler to the div as per the documentation given here.
To solve your issue you need to call a click on the checked divs when you click on none.

I have made a simplified solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/frictionless/BP4vJ/)

You can solve this by changing the click handler for none option to :

```
//Checkbox click - Remove selections 
$("#none").click(function() {
    if ($("#none").attr("checked") == "checked") //IF "NONE OF THESE" IS CHECKED!
    {
        var parentsOfSelectedOptions = $( /*<<selector to get parent>>*/ );
        $(parentsOfSelectedOptions).each(function(item) {
            $(item).click();
        });

        //other actions
    }, function() {
        //other actions
    }
});
```

Comment: Just another question if you dont mind me asking, how would i incorporate the unbind('mouseenter'), and addClass/remove class to each of the individual option boxes when selected? also the removal of class when NONE is selected?

  $(function() {
    var turnOn = function() {
        $('.msg').html('1');
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true);
        $('#none').attr('checked', false);
  $(".option5").addClass('red');
        $(".option5").unbind("mouseenter");
    };
I tried that, but if i add other options to it, it applies it to al options when 1 is selected.

Comment: I'll try and post a solution soon could only post this comment ad I am travelling